# Is it safe to finish an android activity from a background thread?

Tags: android, thread-safety, android-activity

In Android, is it safe to call `Activity.finish()` from a background thread, or can it only called from the main thread? The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) doesn't mention anything about thread safety of this method.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it is not.

The code uses at least one variable, mFinished, without synchronization.  Full stop.

```
   public void finish() {
    if (mParent == null) {
        int resultCode;
        Intent resultData;
        synchronized (this) {
            resultCode = mResultCode;
            resultData = mResultData;
        }
        if (false) Log.v(TAG, "Finishing self: token=" + mToken);
        try {
            if (resultData != null) {
                resultData.setAllowFds(false);
            }
            if (ActivityManagerNative.getDefault()
                .finishActivity(mToken, resultCode, resultData)) {
                mFinished = true;
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // Empty
        }
    } else {
        mParent.finishFromChild(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anywhere in the documentation that says this? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: No, I had to go read code.  It's a great question because, although Activity methods are typically called from a single thread, Service methods are routinely called from multiple (Binder) threads.

Comment: Submitted an issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63339&thanks=63339&ts=1386343166

Comment: @HeathBorders I see your issue was closed as Obsolete. Could it be the `finish()` code changed in the latest SDK (waiting for the sources to download now). The doc definitely has not changed.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator The code hasn't changed.  It looks to me as if both mParent and mFinished are accessed wo/synchronization.  Don't understand why the ticket was closed...

Answer (score 0):

Probably the result could be unexpected. I'd use a Handler or some other way to send to the activity the order to kill itself in the next iteration.

Comment: haha. not exactly. You dont know in what point of execution the UI thread is, so it will be conflicting with some other stuff. thats why i wouldnt.  of course your answer is much more especific