# calling .finish() in onBackPressed is preforming differently than calling it else where

Tags: android, kotlin

I have nearly identical pieces of code show below.

In an unrelated section of the code:

```
    thread {
         val result = Intent()
         this@Activity2.setResult(RESPONSE_SUCCESS_CODE, result)
         this@Activity2.finish()
    }
```

and in the onBackPressed method:

```
    thread {
        val result = Intent()
        this@Activity2.setResult(RESPONSE_CANCEL_CODE, result)
        this@Activity2.finish()
    }
```

I would expect these pieces of code to function the same way except for passing a different result code to the calling activity. Except the first piece of code correctly takes us back to the calling activity, while the second piece of code takes us back to an unrelated activity that was fully closed.

So the expected workflow is main -> act1 -> back to main -> act2 -> back to main.

If I do not override the onBackPressed function or if I call the piece of code not in the onBackPressed function I get the expected workflow. Additionally if I run a layout inspector through android studio while in act2 it correctly does not show any instances of act1 since it was fully closed.

But if I call the piece of code in the onBackPressed function I get the following workflow: main -> act1 -> back to main -> act2 -> act1.

I honestly hae no idea why this might be happening.

Comment: Can you add more details of your `act2`? Beside this, Is there any error in your logcat?

Comment: In scenario:
- FirstActivity
- SecondActivity FirstActivity startForResult() SecondActivity. What have you in FirstActivity.onActivityResult()? RESPONSE_CANCEL_CODE and RESPONSE_SUCCESS_CODE are public constants? Using the same constants in all Activities?

Comment: See also, [Is it safe to finish an android activity from a background thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412871/is-it-safe-to-finish-an-android-activity-from-a-background-thread)

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman act2 is a camera activity with a certain detector. It does not put anything else in the intent that it returns other than the status code. When the detector detects what it is looking for it calls the top piece of code. If the user presses the back button it calls the bottom piece. Those are the only two intended ways for the activity to end. Does not seem to be any relevant errors in the logcat.

Comment: @greeble31 I don't know why I had it in a thread as I inherited this code. But moving it out of the thread {} does not change the behavior.

Comment: I am a little unclear about your description, I understand that "main -> act1 -> back to main -> act2 -> act1" is undesirable, but what exactly does that mean? When are you pressing "back", and when are each of the above code snippets running?

Comment: @greeble31 during the camera process (act2) the user is allowed to press the os back button at any point. act2 (which was launched from main) should then go back to main, hit main's onactivityresult where it would handle the RESPONSE_CANCEL_CODE. Right now the breakpoint in onactivityresult is not being hit and instead it is going back to act1 which was already fully closed. I have found a work around where I don't override onBack and instead just interpret a not success as canceled.

Comment: How exactly are you starting act1 and act2? And when you say act1 was "fully closed", does that mean you called `finish()`? Or did you press "back", or explicitly re-start the main activity, while on act1?

Comment: @greeble31 Both activities are started from main using startActivityForResult and both were finished using .finish() after using .setResult with some intent.

Comment: How about dumping the value of `getIntent()` (in act1)? That might give you some insight on how it's being started, at least.

Comment: @greeble31 Thanks for the suggestion, but I figured it out. There was a static variable that dictated what step of the process main activity was in. When back was getting pressed it was before the detector in act2 could set it to the correct value. In main it was not hitting the breakpoint in onActivityResult due to going down the act1 path. It was sloppy code that I have changed for a more sensible way of keeping track of the steps in the main activity.